# Yandex maps & Angular: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: angular, yandex-maps

I am using [Yandex maps](https://ddubrava.github.io/angular8-yandex-maps/#/) in Angular. I could use it in several places. But I have faced an issue with [NG Zorro tabs](https://ng.ant.design/components/tabs/en): `Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`. And The map is not shown. Could you share your solution(for eagrly loaded tabs)? Because I think that It is probable I face this kind of issue in other cases.
Thank you for your answers!

```
<nz-tabset>
  <nz-tab nzTitle="Tab 1">Content of Tab Pane 1</nz-tab>
  <nz-tab nzTitle="Tab 2">
   <div style="height: 400px">
    <ya-map [center]="[44, 55]" [zoom]="12">
      <ya-placemark [geometry]="[44, 55]"></ya-placemark>
    </ya-map>
  </div>
  </nz-tab>
  <nz-tab nzTitle="Tab 3">Content of Tab Pane 3</nz-tab>
</nz-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I used [lazy load tabs](https://ng.ant.design/components/tabs/en#components-tabs-demo-lazy), and it works.

```
<nz-tabset>
  <nz-tab nzTitle="Tab 1">Content of Tab Pane 1</nz-tab>
  <nz-tab nzTitle="Tab 2">
     <ng-template nz-tab>
        <div style="height: 400px">
           <ya-map [center]="[44, 55]" [zoom]="12">
             <ya-placemark [geometry]="[44, 55]"></ya-placemark>
           </ya-map>
        </div>
     </ng-template>
  </nz-tab>
  <nz-tab nzTitle="Tab 3">Content of Tab Pane 3</nz-tab>
</nz-tabset>
```

I have just wrapped inside of the tab with `<ng-template nz-tab></ng-template>`

Comment: But I do not know why this problem happens in the default tabs mode(eagrly loaded).